# Prove that $\mathbb Q[i]$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I need to prove that $\mathbb Q[i]$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z[i]$. Can someone help me?

Comment: What about you just check the definitions?

Answer (score 2):

If you know your theorems about field of fractions, you can prove it using the universal properties for fields of fractions. Alternatively, you know that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is a field (because $x^2+1$) is irreducible. Can you find a map
$$
\phi: \mathbb{Q}[i] \to \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle
$$
and prove it is an isomorphism? [Hint: What should $i$ map to?]